# Insert List of Data in DB through Arraylist

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I am trying to insert the set of data in the Room Db with list of Users, i am not able to pass the data to the entity Class. is there anyway to insert the data please help me out. Thank You.

var userDetails = User()

userDetails.username = "Karthik"

i am not able to assign the "Karthik" to userName.

Comment: Post a snippet on the code you want to use to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

```
 Create a Dao for UserDetailDao  `
        @Dao
        interface UserDetailDao {
        @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
            fun insert(userDetails: User)`

//If you want to update or insert a lists then you can do as
     @Transaction
        suspend fun insertUserDetails( userDetails: List<User>) {
            // delete your row on basis of primary key
            // then iterate list and insert 
            userDetails.forEach {
                insert(it)
            }
        }
     }
```

and then in your repository class or viewmodel you can update your table

```
var userDetails = User()

userDetails.username = "Karthik"
```

and then use

```
dao.insert(userDetails)
```